# Doctrine can't generate relations

Tags: doctrine, symfony

Note: I did have done some searches before I ask.

Here is my problem:

I have two entities: One is Channel, and the other one is Plugin, a channel can have many plugins, below is the code,

Channel:

```
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo; // gedmo annotations

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Mikay\MikiBundle\Entity\Channel
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="channels")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Mikay\MikiBundle\Entity\ChannelRepository")
 */
<?php
class Channel
{
  /**     
   * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Plugin", mappedBy="channel")
   */
  private $plugins;
```

Plugin:

```
 use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Mikay\MikiBundle\Entity\Plugin
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="plugins")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Mikay\MikiBundle\Entity\PluginRepository")
 */
<?php
class Plugin
{
  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Channel", inversedBy="plugins")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="channel_id", referencedColumnName="id")
   */
  private $channel;
```

I used this command to update the database, but it never created the relation between the two tables.

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

So, what's the problem, could it be some config errors?

**EDIT:**

Note: 
Don't add

```
@ORM\Column(name="channel_id", type="integer")
```

this kind annonation in Plugin entity, or it will not generate the relations between two tables, that's the cause of my problem.

Comment: You can remove the JoinColumn declaration, it is useless. What makes you say the relation was never created? What happens when you remove the declarations, update your schema, set back the declarations and run `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` ?

Comment: Thanks, it seems that all my code are correct, and dcotrine can generate relations between table now. I'll close this question. Yeah, the JoinColumn statement is unnecessary. Thanks again.

Comment: And you only need to specify the relation in the owning side, the inverse side is not necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll repeat it here again. **Don't add**

```
@ORM\Column(name="channel_id", type="integer")
```

this type of annonation on the property that references other entity, in my case, is the channel property of the Plugin entity, or it will not generate the relations between two tables, that's the cause of my problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell doctrine that these are entities.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Channel
{
```

Here is a quick way to verify that doctrine can see your entities:

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:info
```

Comment: I do have the  @ORM\Entity() declaration, I'll update my question to add this, and I can see my entities using doctrine:mapping:info command.